# Docker and travis ci faling on build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to dockerize my app as part of travis ci so i can then publish it to docker hub:

I have set up my Dockerfile, docker-compose and travis.yml
when the pipeline in github finishes i get this error message:

```
0.60s$ docker run mysite /bin/sh -c "cd /root/mysite; bundle exec rake test"
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /root/mysite
/bin/sh: 1: bundle: not found
The command "docker run mysite /bin/sh -c "cd /root/mysite; bundle exec rake test"" failed and exited with 127 during .
```

My Dockerfile:

```
#Server
FROM node:latest

#create app dir in the container
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

#sets working direcotry for the app
#this allows to run all the comand
#like RUN CMD etc.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm config set strict-ssl false
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3006

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:unsafe" ]
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
```

travis.yml:

```
sudo: required

    language: node_js

node_js:
  - "stable"

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker build -t mysite .
  - docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:80:4567 mysite /bin/sh -c "cd /root/mysite; bundle exec foreman start;"
  - docker ps -a
  - docker run mysite /bin/sh -c "cd /root/mysite; bundle exec rake test"
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules    
script:
  - bundle exec rake test
  - npm test
  - npm run build
```

I have tried running the comands from travis yml locally and get the same error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /usr/src/app/mysite
/bin/sh: 1: bundle: not found
```

I tried going into the container to see if they directories are matching but the container always exits right after it starts

Comment: ps. I am going through this documentation: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/#building-a-docker-image-from-a-dockerfile

Comment: you have node but not ruby here too. thats a strange conflict.

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry i dont understand what u mean

Comment: There is a wrong indentation inside your travis yaml. You should remove the whitespaces before your `language` label.

Comment: Hey @SiadArdroumli just noticed but its how stackoverflow formatted my code, the intedation in my file is correct.

Comment: Do you use ruby somewhere? If not remove all lines containing `bundle exec`.

Answer (score 0):

to execute a command on an existing running container you must call 'docker exec' and not 'docker run'

Answer (score 0):

You possible mixed up `node_js` and `ruby`. Rewrite your `.travis.yml` to something like:

```
sudo: required
language: node_js
node_js: 
  - "stable"
cache:
  directories:
    - "node_modules"
services:
  - docker
before_install:
  - docker build -t mysite:travis-$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER .
script:
  - npm test
  - npm run build
  - docker images "$DOCKER_USERNAME"/mysite
after_success:
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" ]; then
    docker login -u="$DOCKER_USERNAME" -p="$DOCKER_PASSWORD";
    docker tag mysite:travis-$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER "$DOCKER_USERNAME"/mysite:travis-$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER;
    docker push "$DOCKER_USERNAME"/mysite:travis-$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER;
fi
```

Comment: Hey this seems to be a good solution thank you, but on docker login I get a error: 
`0.05s$ if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" ]; then docker tag mysite:travis-$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER "$DOCKER_USERNAME"/mysite:travis-$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER; echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin docker push "$DOCKER_USERNAME"/mysite:travis-$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER; fi
"docker login" requires at most 1 argument.
See 'docker login --help'.
Usage:  docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]
Log in to a Docker registry
Done. Your build exited with 0.`

I have added my ENV vars in travis